# Printing information from a list of employees

Tags: python

I am new to this.  I have created a list of information for 5 'employees'.  I am trying to ask which employee the user wants to print the information for.  How do I prompt the user to select from employee 1-5, and print the number of employee they select from the list I've created?  I have this command-

```
pick = input('Select Employee 1-5 to print their information:')
```

Then I have this list-

```
names = (employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5)
```

If they select employee1, I need it to print `names[0]`. If they select employee2, I need it to print `names[1]`, and so on...

I tried everything.  I put:

```
pick = input('Select Employee 1-5 to print their information:')
print(pick)
print(names(pick))
```

When it threw an error, I would put `print(names[])` and it would say:

```
Select Employee 1-5 to print their information:ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 69, in <module>
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Or I tried:

```
pick = input('Select Employee 1-5 to print their information:')
print(pick)
print(names[])
```

and it said:

```
"ERROR!
  File "<string>", line 69
    print(names[])
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

Comment: What’s the relevance of the [tag:activity-finish] tag you’ve chosen, exactly?

Comment: “*Then I have this list- names = (employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5)*” What you have is a `tuple` which is different than a `list` in Python. Where are each of these `employee#` variables defined? Can you show us your code as a [mre]?

Comment: You will not learn Python by guess-and-checking syntax. If you don't know the difference between `()` and `[]` and are simply throwing tokens at a wall to see what the interpreter will accept, then you're not going to get anywhere. Start at the basics, with a good [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). And then, if you have trouble, odds are you'll be able to identify the problem yourself rather than keyboard smashing in an attempt to appease the Python interpreter.

Comment: From where did you ascertain that `print(names[])` would accomplish what you seem to be attempting? Can you link the source docs on which you’re basing this assertion so that we might be able to shed some light on where your interpretation deviated from the syntax of the language?

Comment: Further, can you share what the expected user input is? A single digit? A string?

Comment: @Silvio Good advice, but I just want to point out that the official Python Tutorial is generally for people who already know how to code. The [section on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) is easy enough to understand, but it has a bunch of asides that a beginner wouldn't understand easily, like the stuff about types and copies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](/q/20449427/4518341) That seems to be the *main* thing you're stuck on, but it's not really clear since you're also dealing with other things like syntax issues, and like esqew said, it's not clear what the input is.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

names = ("employee1", "employee2", "employee3", "employee4","employee5")

First of all you need to define your str values using " ".

Second step is:

```
print(names[0])
```

Please note that, if you want to call value from tuple, you need to remeber about correct bracket

**(names[0])**

Next step looks like this:

```
pick = int(input('Select Employee 1-5 to print their information:'))
print(pick)
print(names[pick])
```

Also you need to rememeber, that input by default is using str, so you need to convert it into int.

Using **int()** function

Answer (score -1):

use a `for` loop with `enumerate` to generate and print a dictionary of options on-the-fly.

```py
names = ('employee1', 'employee2', 'employee3', 'employee4', 'employee5')

options = {}
for i, name in enumerate(names, 1):
    options[i] = name
    print(f'{i}: {name}')
pick = int(input('Select Employee 1-5 to print their information:'))
if pick in options:
    print(pick, options[pick])
else:
    print(pick, 'not an option')
```

Comment: Personally, I'd rather generate and print in separate steps: `options = dict(enumerate(names, 1)); for i, name in options.items(): print(f'{i}: {name}')`. That lets you move things around more easily later if needed.

Answer (score -2):

`input()` returns a string value.  So you need to convert that to an integer to use it as an index into your employee list:

```
pick = input('Select Employee 1-5 to print their information:') 
pick = int(pick)
```

Also, python tuples and lists are indexed starting at zero, not one, so you need to subtract one from the number they entered:

```
print(names[pick-1])
```